# Book where a woman has seizures and is given a device like a garage door opener that sends her back in time

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel

Not sure who the author is. The device is like the remote control. I can't remember the time period she goes back to but she goes several times.

At one point she is in jail. A doctor gives her the device to help stop her seizures.

At one point it stops working so she takes it to a repair shop and they think it is an actual garage door remote so they make it more powerful than it was intended. I think she gets stuck in the past.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you tells us anything else about the plot or characters? Like, who gave the woman the device? What time period did she travel back to? And what happened when she got there?

Comment: Isn't a "garage door opener" the mechanism that raises and lowers a garage door? Is her time travel device like that, or do you mean that it's like a **remote control** for a garage door opener?

Comment: The device is like the remote control. I can't remember the time period she goes back to but she goes several times. At one point she is in jail. A doctor gives her the device to help stop her seizures. At one point it stops working so she takes it to a repair shop and they think it is an actual garage door remote so they make it more powerful than it was intended. I think she gets stuck in the past.